# AFNetworking - call function inside

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking and i have a question about it, i want call one different function when return value correct

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString

                     parameters:(id)parameters

                        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success

                        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure

{

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation
*requestOperation, __unused id responseObject) {

        if (success) {

            int status = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Status"] intValue];



            else if(status == -1)

            {

                [self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, __unused id responseObject) {

                    if (success) {

                        NSLog(@"adfasdfasdfasdf");

                        success(requestOperation,responseObject);

                    }

                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error) {

                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);

                    failure(nil, error);

                }];



            }

            else

                success(requestOperation,responseObject);

        }

    } failure:failure];

    operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

    operation.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;

    [self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];



    return operation;

}
```

when status = -1. I'll call more function with param above, but dosen't work.

```
else if(status == -1)

            {

                [self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, __unused id responseObject) {

                    if (success) {

                        NSLog(@"adfasdfasdfasdf");

                        success(requestOperation,responseObject);

                    }

                } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error) {

                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);

                    failure(nil, error);

                }];



            }
```

run app and I bug function not call to success or failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check success of failure with condition in AFNetworking. AFNetworking provide block.

Follow below code :

```
- (AFHTTPRequestOperation *)GET:(NSString *)URLString

                 parameters:(id)parameters

                    success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success

                    failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure

{

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation
*requestOperation, __unused id responseObject) {


        int status = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Status"] intValue];


       if(status == -1)

        {

            [self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation, __unused id responseObject) {


                    NSLog(@"adfasdfasdfasdf");

                    success(requestOperation,responseObject);



            } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation * operation, NSError *error) {

                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);

                failure(nil, error);

            }];



        }

        else

            success(requestOperation,responseObject);

    }

} failure:failure];

operation.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

operation.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = NO;

[self.operationQueue addOperation:operation];



return operation;

}
```

Comment: I meant, then status = -1 Method "[self HTTPRequestOperationWithHTTPMethod:@"GET" URLString:URLString " dosen't work. How to fix it.

Comment: First did you remove if condition on success ? check my code i have removed condition on success.

Comment: Wlcm.. You can upvote if it helps you. Happiee coding :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (success) {

        int status = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"Status"] intValue];



        else if(status == -1)

        {
```

are you sure this if and else if are a pair?